# Validacion de ingreso de texto JS

Tags: javascript, regex

He estado intentando validar unos ingreso de datos en un formulario con JS pero no me ha funcionado, ya que necesito que me permita ingresar todas las letras del alfabeto, en mayus  y minuscula ademas de los siguientes caracteres /-_. y que ademas solo soporte hasta 75 caracteres.

```
function caracteresEspeciales(div){
    var texto   = $("#"+div).val();
    var regex   = new RegExp(/[^A-Za-z() \/-._{75}]/g);

    $("#"+div).val(texto.replace(regex,""));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- En la regex `[^A-Za-z() \/-._{75}]` tienes un problema muy gordo.

  Y es que empiezas con  `^` y este caracter, dentro de `[ ]` indica que **no coincida** nada de lo especificado dentro.

  Ergo tu regex está validando que no contenga letras, paréntesis, etc...
- Otro fallo es que estás poniendo la **validación de longitud de la cadena dentro** de los `[ ]` y no fuera.

  Además, la longitud si es solo un numero, indica el numero exacto de ocurrencias. en tu caso las cadenas validas serían solo las que tengan 75 caracteres exacto. Tienes que indicar un numero mínimo como `{0,75}`
- Otro detalle de tu regex es que **no escapas el guión**. Has de poner `\` delante para que no piense que es un rango de caracteres como `a-z`

---

La regex correcta sería:

```
new RegExp(/^[a-z\/\-._]{0,75}$/gi)
```

Añadiendo el flag `i` para que no tenga en cuenta las minúsculas/mayúsculas
y tambien el caracter `^` y `$` que indican el principio y final de la cadena

<sub>Nota: Esto no tendrá en cuenta letras con acento. Para tenerlos en cuenta, has de añadir el rango `\u00E0-\u00FC` dentro de los `[]`</sub>

Comment: Muchas Gracias !